# How to use composer audit programmatically

Tags: composer-php, audit

I love the new `composer audit` functionality added to 2.4 (*cf. [`php composer.phar audit`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#audit); [PHP.Watch](https://php.watch/articles/composer-audit)*).

Now I would love to be able to programmatically call that functionality for a given `composer.lock` file (or if needed the associated `composer.json` as well)

By programmatically I mean either a static class or a PHP object which I have to create to do something like:

```
$auditor = new ComposerAuditor();
$result = $auditor->audit($composerJson, $composerLock);
```

`$result` would then contain an array, object or whatever which contains all the audit results.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that performs the auditing itself is marked as internal, and so probably not a great idea (or supported) to use directly.

Composer can output the results of the audit as JSON however, with `composer audit -f json` and so you could easily call that, then capture & parse the output.

```
# portion of a Symfony console command reading 
# a composer file from elsewhere on the local disc
$process = new Process(['php','/usr/local/bin/composer','audit', '--format=json', '--no-interaction']);
$process->setWorkingDirectory($path);
$process->run();

$arr = json_decode($process->getOutput(), true, flags: JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

Comment: Thanks Alister for the quick answer! I am asking to use it programmatically because I have a system which manages multiple websites and one new feature I would like to add is a sort of "security audit notification".
Once per day I fetch the `composer.lock` and `composer.json` files (could theoretically save them locally) and then perform actions upon it.
So I would be forced to write them into my local filesystem and then perform a `shell_exec('composer audit');` on it to use that feature?

Comment: Hey Alister, sorry but your answer is only partially correct because composer unfortunately doesn't allow pure `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files to be audited. One actually has to install the packages via `composer install` and then perform a `composer audit` on it to actually get an output.

Comment: Seems like I was wrong because one can add the option `--locked` to only look at the `composer.lock` file instead of the installed versions.